# What does Pytorch's nn.Linear(x,y) return?

Tags: class, oop, pytorch

I am new to object orientation, and I am having troubles understanding the following:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class mynet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 64)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
```

The line `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 64)`  is supposed to create a member variable fc1 to my class, right? But what is the return value of nn.Linear(20, 64)?

According to the documentation, nn.Linear is defined as
`class torch.nn.Linear(in_features: int, out_features: int, bias: bool = True)`.

However, in my basic OOP tutorial I have only seen something like `class CLASSNAME(BASECLASS)` so that the class CLASSNAME inherits from BASECLASS. What does the documentation mean with its way of writing all that stuff in between the brackets?

Also, the line `x=fc1(x)` somehow makes it look as if fc1 was a function now.

I seem to lack OOP knowledge here... Any help appreciated!

Comment: `self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 64)` is creating a new instance of an `nn.Linear` class and initializing the class using positional arguments `20` and `64` corresponding to `in_features` and `out_features`. The arguments in the documentation are the expected arguments to be passed to `nn.Linear`'s `__init__` method. This class is **callable** since it's parent class, `nn.Module`, implements a special method named `__call__`. That means you can treat `self.fc1` like a function and do things like `x = self.fc1(x)`, which is equivalent to `x = self.fc1.__call__(x)`.

Comment: @jodag please post such nice answers as answers not as comments.

Comment: @jodag thank you very much. So there are callable class instances. And the line in the documentation then seems to list the arguments that the __init__( ) method is expecting, so that they need to be passed when the instance is created.

Comment: @prosti fair point

Comment: @SchroedingersLion Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a little examination:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nnn
fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 64)
print(fc1, type(fc1))
ret = fc1(torch.randn(20))
print(ret, type(ret), ret.shape)
```

Out:

```
Linear(in_features=20, out_features=64, bias=True) <class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'>
tensor([-0.2795,  0.8476, -0.8207,  0.3943,  0.1464, -0.2174,  0.6605,  0.6072,
        -0.6881, -0.1118,  0.8226,  0.1515,  1.3658,  0.0814, -0.8751, -0.9587,
         0.1310,  0.2539, -0.3072, -0.0225,  0.4663, -0.0019,  0.0404,  0.9279,
         0.4948, -0.3420,  0.9061,  0.1752,  0.1809,  0.5917, -0.1010, -0.3210,
         1.1910,  0.5145,  0.2254,  0.2077, -0.0040, -0.6406, -0.1885,  0.5270,
         0.0824, -0.0787,  1.5140, -0.7958,  1.1727,  0.1862, -1.0700,  0.0431,
         0.6849,  0.1393,  0.7547,  0.0917, -0.3264, -0.2152, -0.0728, -0.6441,
        -0.1162,  0.4154,  0.3486, -0.1693,  0.6697,  0.0229,  0.0311,  0.1433],
       grad_fn=<AddBackward0>) <class 'torch.Tensor'> torch.Size([64])
```

`fc1` is of type `class 'torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear'`.
It needs some "juice" to work. In your case it needs the input tensor `torch.randn(20)` to return the output of  `torch.Size([64])`.

So `fc1` is a class instance that you can run with `()` in which case the `forward()` method of a class `nn.Linear` will be called.

In most cases when working with your modules (like `mynet` in your case) you will list the modules in `__init__`, and then in the `forward` of your module you will be defining what will happen (the behavior).

The three kind of modules in PyTorch are:

- Functional modules
- Default modules
- Custom modules

Custom modules like `mynet` you created typically use default modules:

- nn.Identity()
- nn.Embedding()
- nn.Linear()
- nn.Conv2d()
- nn.BatchNorm() (BxHxW)
- nn.LayerNorm() (CxHxW)
- nn.Dropout()
- nn.ReLU()

And many many other modules that I haven't set. But of course, you can create custom modules without any default modules, just by using `nn.Parameter()`, see the last example.

The third kind functional modules are defined [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html).

Also check [`nn.Linear`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/5dd288eb066bc178a89447453c7fba961a3e0174/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L34) implementation. You may note the `F.linear()` functional module is used.

You may test the naive implementation of Linear from [Fastai Book](https://github.com/fastai/fastbook/blob/dd985841b6599d238e5ccb1e590f255ad6a66853/clean/17_foundations.ipynb):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import math

class Linear(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out):
        super().__init__()
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_out, n_in) * math.sqrt(2/n_in))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(n_out))
    
    def forward(self, x): return x @ self.weight.T + self.bias
    
fc = Linear(20,64)
ret = fc(torch.randn(20))
print(ret.shape) # 64
```

You may try to understand the difference between the naive implementation provided inside PyTorch.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was unaware of callable class instances.

Answer (score 5):

First lets take a look at this

```py
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 64)
```

This part is probably familiar to someone with a basic understanding of python and OOP. Here we are simply creating a new instance of an `nn.Linear` class and initializing the class using positional arguments `20` and `64` corresponding to `in_features` and `out_features` respectively. The arguments in the documentation are the expected arguments to be passed to `nn.Linear`'s `__init__` method.

Now for the part that's probably a little more confusing

```py
x = self.fc1(x)
```

The `nn.Linear` class is a **callable** since it's parent class, `nn.Module`, implements a special method named `__call__`. That means you can treat `self.fc1` like a function and do things like `x = self.fc1(x)`, which is equivalent to `x = self.fc1.__call__(x)`.